# Hibernate, load schema from file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

In Hibernate, I can use hbm2dll tool to import data files after hibernate generates the schema from my model. This is fine, but I want to load the file with my database schema and make hibernate use that instead of generating one.

Let's say I have some database configured in my hibernate config

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:."/>
```

Now before I run my test I want to load the db with some schema defined in my schema.sql file. **And I don't want to use Spring**, I know there is support for it there.

I know I could use **hibernate.hbm2ddl** to generate schema when SessionFactory is created but I'd rather want to load my manually defined schema. Something like `<jdbc:embedded-database>` from spring-jdbc.

Is there any support for that in Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

[link1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch12s09.html) and [link2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) might help you out.

Also you can set `hibernate.hbm2ddl` to `none`, and add your `import.sql` file in the classpath which will be executed at the server startup.

Comment: I said I don't want to use Spring, hbm2ddl doesn't have option "none" regarding  your second suggestion.